# Where can I ask about moving only MySQL database to Amazon EC2 servers?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask the following question:

> **Move only MySQL database to Amazon EC2 servers?**
>
> I have a website with users and a payment system (nothing special) which has a 5 GB big MySQL database.
>
> I consider moving the database file to Amazon servers, so I move only the .sql file and the rest (PHP, HTML, etc.) remains. Is this legitimate, and will it work?
>
> I've red already a lot about this and I am not sure whether it is a good idea. Some topics say it's not a good idea to move a database file to EC2, I will need ECB for a relational database file like MySQL.
>
> And the Amazon FAQ, etc. are filled with so much information I can hardly decide what is important and what's not.
>
> Can someone comment on this? That would be helpful.
>
> P.S.: I am not the owner, the main person is too busy ATM. and asked me to do the research.

On which Stack Exchange site can I ask this question as I expect it to be off-topic for Stack Overflow?

Comment: Well, it is undoubtedly off-topic on the Meta site. I would say it is also off-topic on Stack Overflow. Not sure where else it would be appropriate. There is a master list of sites [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic); no guarantees.

Comment: Okay thanks, I search somewhere else.

Comment: I've rewritten this post so it becomes a site recommendation question. You  might get a better advice on where and how to post your actual question.

Comment: You might find [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141942/best-stackexchange-site-for-asking-about-amazon-aws) useful.

Comment: Having a remote database will likely give you a huge performance hit. (Plus there'd actually have to be mySQL running on the new server; just moving the dump file will achieve nothing, it has to be imported)